# How to define byte array in vb6 and send it with Winsock

Tags: arrays, vb6

Well in c# it would look like:

```
Byte[] ulaznipodaci = new Byte[] { 0x08, 0x3F, 0x20, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00 };
sck.Send(ulaznipodaci);
```

I need this kind of code in vb6. I tried:

```
Dim ulaznipodaci() As Byte
ulaznipodaci = Array(&H8, &H3F, &H20, &H3, &H0, &H0, &H5, &H0)
Winsock2.SendData ulaznipodaci
```

But this code gives me an error on the line `ulaznipodaci = Array(&H8, &H3F, &H20, &H3, &H0, &H0, &H5, &H0)`

saying: Run time error '13':
Type mismatch.

I searched google but couldn't find anything. Please help, I'm kinda new in vb6.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is about another game-cheat bot project, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB6, you have to define your array's bounds and then populate each item separately:

```
Dim ulaznipodaci(7) As Byte 
'// VB6 array is zero based unless you specify lower to upper bounds

ulaznipodaci(0) = &H8
ulaznipodaci(1) = &H3F
ulaznipodaci(2) = &H20
ulaznipodaci(3) = &H3
ulaznipodaci(4) = &H0
ulaznipodaci(5) = &H0
ulaznipodaci(6) = &H5
ulaznipodaci(7) = &H0
```

If, later you need to add more items:

```
ReDim Preserve ulaznipodaci(8)

ulaznipodaci(8) = &H0
```

Answer (score 0):

.. or for example store in a string and then read in cycle

St="&H8, &H3F, &H20, &H3, &H0, &H0, &H5, &H0"

for i = 1 to N

pos = (i-1)*6 ' poition &
 ulaznipodaci(i)=mid(St,pos,4)  ' we do not need "," and a space

next